# Public List error when setting up a table view in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xcode, macos, visual-studio, cocoa

I'm trying to work on a table view in Xcode and Visual studio, and am setting it up to import data, but I keep getting an error in the List.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AppKit;

namespace HCATester
{
    public class NormsLogDataSource : NSTableViewDataSource
    {
        public NormsLogDataSource(){}

        public List Norms = new List();
        public override nint GetRowCount(NSTableView tableView)
        {
            return Norms.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I select it to see what's wrong, this is what I get:

> Implements the System.Collections.Generic.IList interface. The size of a List is dynamically increased as required. A List is not guaranteed to be sorted. It is the programmer's responsibility to sort the List prior to performing operations (such as BinarySearch) that require a List to be sorted. Indexing operations are required to perform in constant access time; that is, O(1).

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, good to see a good question from a new user. Can you add what the error is? Your quoted part seems more like the documentation for the Class `List`. Also what List are you using and what does it contain (datatype)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the declaration of your `List`. You are using the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace which (among other collections) contains the generic `List<T>`. But you aren't specifying the generic type parameter.

You see, before we had generics, we used `ArrayList` which just held a collection of `objects`, so we'd always need to cast it to what we actually wanted. For example, if we want a ArrayList of integers we could declare our list like this:

```cs
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
```

But when using it we would need to cast our item from `object` to whatever type we wanted like so:

```cs
int item1 = (int) list[0];
int item2 = (int) list[1];
// ...
```

This gets confusing and error prone, for example if a Method takes an `ArrayList` as a parameter you'd always need to make sure every element of said ArrayList was of the right type.
In come Generics and the generic `List<T>`, with it we can define a strongly typed List. The same example as above but using List is much easier to read and understand:

```cs
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(1);
list.Add(1);

int item1 = list[0];
int item2 = list[1];
// ...
```

Now we don't need to cast our object, as we already know what datatype it is. This also adds a lot more security, as we can define what types are valid inside a List.

Now to answer your question, you need to specify the datatype you are using, you said `string` so I'll show you how. All you need to do is replace your line where you are declaring the List with this:

```cs
public List<string> Norms = new List<string>();
```

P.S the generic () part of a class can be read as "of" or "for", e.g `List<T>` would be read as "A List of T", `List<int>` would be "A List of Integers". And `ViewModel<TView>` would be read as "A ViewModel for TView"

Comment: Thank you, MindSwipe. The data in the list are all strings of text, the list consisting of "NormName", "Domain", "Description" and "Requirements"